# Copy constructor parameter is 0

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I am subtracting two Date objects and in my overloaded minus operator I return an instance of another Date class I create. But for some reason, after the overloaded minus function is complete and the copy constructor gets called from initialization, the parameter is 0. Why is this.

//Date.h

```
class Date
{
    int month, day, year;
    Date *datePtr = this;
public:
    Date();
    Date(Date &);
    bool operator==(const Date& obj);
    bool operator>(const Date& obj);
    Date operator-(const Date& obj);
    Date operator=(const Date& obj);

    friend istream &operator>>(istream& in, Date &obj);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream& out, Date &obj);
};
```

//test.cpp

```
cout << "Date 2 is later in time than Date 1 by \n";
Date temp = date2 - date1; //Overloaded minus called then Copy Constructor from initialization
cout << temp << endl;
```

//date implmentation

```
Date Date::operator-(const Date& obj)
{
    Date tempDate = *this;

    if (tempDate.datePtr->day >= obj.day)
    {
        tempDate.datePtr->day = tempDate.datePtr->day - obj.day;
    }
    else
    {
        tempDate.datePtr->day = tempDate.datePtr->day + 30;
        tempDate.datePtr->day = tempDate.datePtr->day - obj.day;
    }
    if (tempDate.datePtr->month > 1)
    {
        tempDate.datePtr->month = tempDate.datePtr->month - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        tempDate.datePtr->month = 12;
        tempDate.datePtr->year = tempDate.datePtr->year - 1;
    }

    if (tempDate.datePtr->month >= obj.month)
    {
        tempDate.datePtr->month = tempDate.datePtr->month - obj.month;
    }
    else
    {
        tempDate.datePtr->month = tempDate.datePtr->month + 12;
        tempDate.datePtr->month = tempDate.datePtr->month - obj.month;
        tempDate.datePtr->year = tempDate.datePtr->year - 1;
    }

    tempDate.datePtr->year = tempDate.datePtr->year - obj.year;
    return tempDate;
}
```

//copy constructor

```
Date::Date(Date &obj)
{    /*obj.month, day and year is 0 here but should be the value from return Date instance from overloaded minus function.*/
    cout << "INSIDE COPY CONSTRUCTOR" << obj.month << "/" << obj.day << endl;
    datePtr = new Date;
    (*datePtr).month = obj.month;
    (*datePtr).day = obj.day;
    (*datePtr).year = obj.year;
}
```

Comment: `operator = (const Date&)` should be returning a reference to `this`, not a brand new `Date` object.  More specifically `Date& operator=(const Date&);` should be the signature.

Comment: Your saying the operator= gets called from `Date temp = date1 - date2`?

Comment: Post a [mcve] with a `main` function that demonstrates the error.  And yes, your `operator=`, if called, will cause all sorts of grief.

Comment: The reason I ask is I thought the operator= only gets called from assignment and not initialization. 
`Date temp = date1 - date2 //initialization`
`Date temp
temp = date1 - date2`

Comment: The comment section is for comments, not for answers.  I commented on your code, and it will cause issues if you happen to have invoked assignment.  We don't know this until you post a [mcve].  Also, what is the `Date*` member for anyway?  Why such a weird implementation of a `Date` class?

Comment: Just for a challenge

Comment: Well, you really should be overloading `-=` and just have `-` call `-=` in a one or two line function.

Comment: `Date *datePtr = this;`  --- why would you do that

Comment: Because YOLO?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually save the datePtr object to the current one in your copy constructor. You do set the month/day/year for datePtr, but that doesn't affect the current instance of the object. This is because (in your header file), despite the fact that you set datePtr = this, that does not mean datePtr *is* this. It simply points to the address of this (or in other words, the current instantiation). Calling datePtr = new Date; simply changes where datePtr points, not the data that it points to. Change your copy constructor to something like this:

```
Date::Date(const Date &obj)
{
    this->month = obj.month;
    this->year = obj.year;
    this->day = obj.day;
}
```

As someone in the comments points out, a member initialization list would also be a way to do this. There is a lot that goes into why you should use them, and a good place to read up on it is here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/when-do-we-use-initializer-list-in-c/

In case you wanted to see it, this is how the code would look using a member initialization list:

```
Date::Date(const Date &obj) : month(obj.month), year(obj.year), day(obj.day)
{
    // Nothing <3
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. But I don't see the difference between  initializing with `this` and creating a new instance like I am. Is it because I wasnt returning the new instance in the copy constructor? And what is the difference between doing `this->month = obj.month` vs` month = obj.month`

Comment: For this answer, now is a good time to show how to use the member initialization list

Comment: It's because, when you created a new instance, you didn't do anything with it. You certainly did have an object on the heap, and it certainly did have all the correct data. In fact, datePtr pointed to that object on the heap. However, that object on the heap has nothing to do with the current object. It's a completely separate and new object (thus the use of the `new` keyword). `this` still refers to the current object, where as dataPtr no longer refers to the current object.

Comment: @henhen There was no need for pointers in your original code.  There are holes and implementation issues in your code other than pointers.  Maybe you should address those first before introducing things (that need not be introduced).

Comment: Well the reason I created a pointer was because before in my `operator-` function, it was changing the value of the members variables for the `date2` instance in `Date temp = date2 - date1`

Comment: Member initialization achieves the same thing correct? It is just a short hand way of writing out the constructor?
I just tested out your solutiion without using the `this->month day etc` and just use `month = obj.month` and it achieves the same results

Comment: Correct. There are some situations where a MIL is necessary, and very few situations where it shouldn't be used. Your use-case falls into neither of these, so it's up to you how you want to do it (although, MIL is typically preferred).

Comment: @renspaceyi There is one thing that is still unclear to me. In my originial answer's copy constructor, why is member variables `obj.month obj.day obj.year` equal to zero, but when I change to your implmentation, it will show the correct values?

Comment: @henhen Your copy constructor did the following: 1) made `datePtr` point to a `new Date` object, 2) sets the member variables of that new Date object to the values in `obj`. Note that `datePtr` points to a completely different object than it did before. Before (in the header file), you set `datePtr` to be `this`. However, `this` is just a pointer. In other words, when you set `datePtr = new Date;`, you're not actually changing the data stored at the address `this`. What you're changing is the address `datePtr` points to (from `this` to something else on the heap).

Comment: @henhen If you simply never changed the address `datePtr` pointed to, you would have been fine. In other words, your code would work if you commented out the line `datePtr = new Date;`

Comment: I see. I still don’t see how that affects the passed in parameters from ‘Date temp = date2 - date1’ where the overload- returns another temp object that points to *this, so I would assume when I return tempDate, and copy constructor gets invoked, obj.day month year should have correct values and not 0. I even log it out before I create the new Instance.

Comment: It's because a lot is happening behind the scenes in the line `Date temp = date2 - date1`. First, you call the overloaded `-` operator. Then, you call the assignment operator (`=`). In that assignment operator, I'm sure you call the copy constructor (or at least, you should). Thus, in the end, when you call `=`, all you did was change where `this` pointed and then changed the data where it points.

Comment: @renspaceyi I don't think the overloaded assignment operator gets called from `Date temp = date2 - date1` . The reason is I keep reading that overloaded assignment function does not get invoked during initialization. But rather in assignment. `Date temp = date2 - date1 //Initialization of temp, copy constructor called` `Date temp; temp = date2 - date1; // Temp already initialized, copy constructor not called but overloaded assignment called.`